messagebox won't open with certain def
I have a def that is called on by pressing a button but messagebox won't open when it runs. It will open with another def just fine, what's wrong?
btw I haven't touched python in years
I tried having a button that opened a messagebox that displays the currency you selected converted to USD, I thought it would open right up but messagebox won't open.
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox

from pip._vendor.pyparsing.util import col

#Main Code


#GUI
top = tk.Tk()

label = tk.Label(top, text=" ")

clicked = tk.StringVar()
clicked.set( "Select Currency" )

def show():
    label.config(text = clicked.get())

options = [
    "Euro",
    "Dong",
    "Ruble",
    "Pound",
    "Peso",
    "Yen",
    "Rupee"
]

drop = tk.OptionMenu(top, clicked, *options).grid(row =1,column =1)

L1 = tk.Label(top, text="Currency Converter").grid(row =0,column =1)
L2 = tk.Label(top, text="USD").grid(row =2,column =0)
currency_Label = tk.Label(top, textvariable=clicked).grid(row =3,column =0)

enter_box = tk.Entry(top, bd =5)
enter_box.grid(row =2,column =1)

def proces():
    usd_number = enter_box.get()
    usds_number = str(usd_number)
    if usd_number == type(int):
        con_num = float(usd_number)
        cEuro = con_num * .92
        cDong = con_num * 25455
        cRuble = con_num*88.58
        cPound = con_num*.79
        cPeso = con_num*16.92
        cYen = con_num*157.66
        cRupee = con_num*83.37
    

        if clicked.get() == "Euro":
            csEuro = str(cEuro)
            messagebox.showinfo("Converted!", usds_number + " is " + csEuro)
        if clicked.get() == "Dong":
            csDong = str(cDong)
            
        if clicked.get() == "Ruble":
            csRuble = str(cRuble)
            
        if clicked.get() == "Pound":
            csPound = str(cPound)
            
        if clicked.get() == "Peso":
            csPeso = str(cPeso)
            
        if clicked.get() == "Yen":
            csYen = str(cYen)
            
        if clicked.get() == "Rupee":
            csRupee = str(cRupee)
            
        


B = tk.Button(top, text ="Convert", command=proces).grid(row =4,column =1)

top.mainloop()


if usd_number == type(int): is a condition that can never possibly be true.  int is a type, so type(int) is type; nothing the user can possibly enter will be equal to that.

So would is.digit make sure the message comes up only when they enter a number?

.isdigit() would only allow integers - you appear to want to allow fractional values, too, but there isn't a similarly convenient method for checking for digits and decimal points.  The usual approach is to apply float() to the entered value, inside of a try-except so that you can catch invalid entries.

is.digit worked!

command enter_box.get() should gives string - so there is no need to use str(usd_number), If you want to know if you get string with integer then you can try to convert it int(usd_number) and it will raise error if it is not integer - and this can be the best method. But you need float so can directly run float(usd_number) and ti will raise error when it is not float - and you have to use try/excpt to catch error.

if you would like to convert prices to Polish currency Zloty then National Polish Bank has API to get current exchanges as JSON API and you can get it with module urllib.request or requests

you could keep data as dictionary rate = {"Euro"  : 0.92, ...} and get converted value as result = con_num * rate[clicked.get()] (without using if/else and without using many variables cRuble, cEuro, etc.

Popular method to check if string is integer is to use int(usd_number) and it will raise error it string is not integer. And it needs to run it in try/except
But you need float so you should do it with con_num = float(usd_number) (without if)
def proces():
    usd_number = enter_box.get()

    try:
       con_num = float(usd_number)
       # ... rest ...
    except ValueError as ex:
       #print(f'Exception: {ex}') 
       messagebox.showinfo(f"It is not float value: {usd_number}")

To make more readable you can put rest of the code after try/except and return in except to skip rest of the code
def proces():
    usd_number = enter_box.get()

    try:
       con_num = float(usd_number)
    except ValueError as ex:
       #print(f'Exception: {ex}') 
       messagebox.showinfo(f"It is not float value: {usd_number}")
       return  # exit function and skip rest of the code

    # ... rest ...


isdigit() can be good if user will put integer values but it will give False when user will use float value - like "123.45".isdigit()

Full working code with other changes.
I uses dictionary to keep value
rate = {"Euro": 0.92, ...}

and convert it with
result = con_num * rate[clicked.get()]

And I can use keys as options
options = list(sorted(rate.keys()))

so when I add more values in rate then it will automatically show them in OptionMenu
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox

# --- functions ---

#def show():
#    label.config(text = clicked.get())

def proces():
    usd_number = enter_box.get()

    try:
        con_num = float(usd_number)
    except ValueError as ex:
        print(f"Exception: {ex}")        
        messagebox.showinfo("ERROR", f"It is not float value: {usd_number}")
        return
        
    currency = clicked.get()
    
    if currency not in rate:
        messagebox.showinfo("ERROR", "Select currency")
        return

    result = con_num * rate[currency]
    messagebox.showinfo("Converted!", f"{usd_number} USD = {result} {currency}")

# --- main ---

rate = {
    "Euro"  : 0.92,
    "Dong"  : 25455.00,
    "Ruble" : 88.58,
    "Pound" : 0.79,
    "Peso"  : 16.92,
    "Yen"   : 157.66, 
    "Rupee" : 83.37,
}

options = list(sorted(rate.keys()))


# GUI   # PEP8: space afert `#`
top = tk.Tk()

#label = tk.Label(top, text="")

clicked = tk.StringVar(top)
clicked.set("Select Currency")


drop = tk.OptionMenu(top, clicked, *options)
drop.grid(row=1, column=1)  # PEP8: space after `,` not before `=`

label_1 = tk.Label(top, text="Currency Converter")
label_1.grid(row=0, column=1)  

label_2 = tk.Label(top, text="USD")
label_2.grid(row=2, column=0)

#currency_label = tk.Label(top, textvariable=clicked)   # PEP8: `lower_case_names` for variables
#currency_label.grid(row=3, column=0)

enter_box = tk.Entry(top, bd=5)
enter_box.grid(row=2, column=1)

button = tk.Button(top, text="Convert", command=proces)
button.grid(row=4, column=1)

top.mainloop()


PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code
